# jQuery Error with Zurb Foundation 5 (font-family bug)

Tags: jquery, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I have this strange problem with Foundation 5 and jQuery.

An error occurs and javascript won't work any more:

```
jquery.js:1850
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-'Open Sans', sans-serif-slider]
```

The page is quite simple:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">
        <script src="javascripts/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- Some HTML stuff... -->
       <script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
       <script src="javascripts/foundation/foundation.alerts.js"></script>
       <script src="javascripts/custom.js"></script>
       <script>
           $(document).foundation();
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I read through several threads dealing with a similar issue for an early version of Foundation 4. I don't know if my  problem is related or not.

If you met this issue before, help would be much appreciated :)

___EDIT
I just updated the whole stuff with bower to use the latest versions of the different files. But I still get this error :(

__EDIT
I just isolated the problem:

The stylesheet refers to a font-family :

```
html,
p,ul,li,
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family:"Open Sans";
}
```

Disabling the font-family attribute will remove the bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`font-family` should not be attributed to `html` as it leads to that bug.

Use `body` instead:

```
body{
    font-family:"Open Sans";
}
```